# Mysqli Bind Parameters - Update Statement - Referencing column +1

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am wondering if mysqli works when binding a column reference +1 type of field.  Example.

```
UPDATE `table` SET  `sys-helpful-yes` = `sys-helpful-yes`+1 WHERE `id` = 1;
```

When using mysqli bind parameters, it doesn't add the one.

```
UPDATE `table` SET  `sys-helpful-yes` = ? WHERE `id` = 1;
```

I am trying to bind

```
`sys-helpful-yes`+1
```

Wondering if anyone has a workaround.

Comment: Why bind parameters in this case at all? You have fully defined update expression.

Comment: Are there situations when you want to add more than 1?

Comment: Not really.  For this project I am using a framework that auto binds the statement from an array.  So I am trying to work with that system at the moment.  I wanted to make sure I wasn't incorrectly using bind before customizing the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
UPDATE `table` SET  `sys-helpful-yes` = `sys-helpful-yes`+ ? WHERE `id` = 1;
```

and then, of course, only bind `1` ...
(not tested) ?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  You response sparked a idea which worked.  Thanks again.